# How Maven looks for dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have read many documentation and tutorial about getting started with Maven. But few things are still not clear to me :

1) When pom.xml contains `<dependency>`, Maven will put that artifact/JAr in Maven local Repository. Right ?

2) Suppose, I have sub modules in my MAven project. Then what is the correct way to build the project ? one should start from parent module and then go to further sub modules. right ? and that way maven will create dependency jars and put them in local Maven Repo folder ?

3) For example, if my sub module pom.xml contains following dependency. How should I provide it (vd-ps.jar) to Maven so that Maven finds it when I do Maven clean install on Submodule/pom.xml? I mean to say what does Maven require or from where does it generate such user defined vd-ps.jar ? from compiled class files ?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
        <artifactId>vd-ps</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Ok, let me ask directly what I want to achieve: I have following pom.xml. and from it I would like to create a separate maven project (Say PTest) that uses dependencies (jars) of another big multi module maven project. Here :- I have a module named v-parent in my multi module project which has pom.xml in its trunk folder.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
    <artifactId>v-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
  </parent>


    <groupId>com.b.t.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>p_test</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>ptesting</name>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
            <artifactId>v-ps</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

1) Now where should I put this sub module v-parent in my newly created Maven project (PTest) in eclipse ?

I mean how do I exactly make my PTest/pom.xml find this parent jar v-parent.jar ?

I have separate jar file named v-ps.jar. where should I put it exactly (in which structure) in Maven local repo so that it can find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run

```
mvn clean install
```

Your project will be built and the resulting artifact will be 'installed' in your local repository (usually ~/.m2/repository).  So if you build the project which makes the jar com.b.t:vd-ps:1.1.0 this will then be available in your local repository for other projects to use as a dependency.

If you dependency is in another module under the same parent it can in included like so :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
  <artifactId>vd-ps</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version)</version>
</dependency>
```

If you run a

```
mvn clean deploy
```

Your artifact will be built and deployed to the remote repository (Nexus or Artifactory or similar), provided you have the correct config in your pom.xml

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: if says me The artifacts could not be resolved:com.b.t.vd-ps:1.1.0 etc. and I checked that it exists in  ~/.m2/repository/b/t/vd-ps/1.1.0/vd-ps-1-1-0.jar.lastupdated Any idea why would not it find it ?

Comment: `.jar.lastupdated` is not a JAR, just a marker file.

Comment: I suggest you delete the directory ~/.m2/repository/com/b/t/vd-ps/1.1.0 and re-run the mvn build for that project, then check you have a jar file there not a maker file as @Tome has said.

Comment: Sorry but one basic question, When I do maven clean install in maven project, there has to be classes and pom.xml in the project, out of which it will create jar file based on the pom.xml specification and will put in maven repository. Is that correct ? so for eg. one just do maven clean install in  folder having just pom.xml, it will just create a marker file in repo. is that right ? pl correct me or clarify to me.

Comment: @Ragini yes a maven project usually consists of source code and dependencies to other jars.

Comment: @Essex: Is it that when MAven fails to find some dependency, it creates such Markers for jar ? I mean when and why does it generate markup jar file in repository ?

Comment: Yes, usually it means it can't connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

*1) Now where should I put this sub module v-parent in my newly created Maven project (PTest) in eclipse ?
I mean how do I exactly make my PTest/pom.xml find this parent jar v-parent.jar ?*

So in this case "v-parent" will be another project in Eclipse of packaging type "pom". And if you want to build the child project "p_test" and its dependency "v-ps", you could list them as modules in the "v-parent" project's pom file like below:

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
  <artifactId>v-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>p_test</module> <!-- Make sure you provide the right path here -->
    <module>v-ps</module> <!-- Make sure you provide the right path here -->
  </modules>
</project>
```

Now when you run "mvn clean install" on "v-parent" it should build "p_test" and "v-ps" projects and places a copy of their jar files in your local .m2/repository, assuming those projects don't error our during the build. So the parent project acts like an aggregate for the sub-projects and helps building them all at one shot.

*I have separate jar file named v-ps.jar. where should I put it exactly (in which structure) in Maven local repo so that it can find it ?*

If you have the source for this project, then you should include it as part of the "v-parent" project's pom as a module like I mentioned above, and when you build the parent, on success, the jar gets written to your local .m2 repo. Or if you have the source for "v-ps" project, you could directly build that using "mvn clean install" and the jar will be written to the repo.